# DataTables Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatables

Below is the document ready function

```
Script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "GetUser.ashx",
            "sServerMethod": "POST",
            "sAjaxDataProp" : "",
            "aoColumnDefs": [ {
            "aTargets": [ 0 ],
            "mData": "download_link",
            "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
               return '<a href="/UserDetail.aspx?ID='+data+'">Detail</a>';
             }
           } ],
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "LoginId" },
                { "mData": "Name" },
                { "mData": "CreatedDate" }
            ]
        });
```

Below is the respond from server (GetUser.ashx)

```
[
    {
        "UserId": "1",
        "LoginId": "white.smith",
        "Activated": "Y",
        "Name": "Test Account",
        "LastName": "Liu",
        "Email": "white.smith@logical.com",
        "CreatedDate": "1/21/2014 12:03:00 PM",
        "EntityState": "2",
        "EntityKey": "System.Data.EntityKey"
    },
More Data...
]
```

Below is the html table where the data should be put

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th width="15%">User Detail</th>
            <th width="15%">LoginID</th>
            <th width="15%">Name</th>
            <th width="15%">Created Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
             <th width="15%">User Detail</th>
            <th width="15%">LoginID</th>
            <th width="15%">Name</th>
            <th width="15%">Created Date</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Expected result:

[image]

But I came across a problem:

While the page is loading, there was an uncaught exception from the browser:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

When I further check, it came from line 2037 of jquery.dataTables.js

```
var aData = _fnGetObjectDataFn( oSettings.sAjaxDataProp )( json );
```

[image]

I checked that the json was valid, but the "aData" was null, why this happen?

Comment: You can view the call stack and trace back to the web page the source of the problem...

Comment: the following properties are not separated with a comma. Is this a type? `"Email": "white.smith@logical.com"
        "CreatedDate": "1/21/2014 12:03:00 PM"
        "EntityState": "2",
        "EntityKey": "System.Data.EntityKey"`

Comment: @Nilesh It's not a type, it's just that I forgot to add a comma in this post, I've added it back here

Comment: Sorry I meant a typo not type :)

Comment: Depend version DT, look http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11901/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-jquery-datatables-js-1918

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As there are 4 columns, add the following in "aoColumns":

```
"aoColumns": [
  { "mData": null },  // for User Detail
  { "mData": "LoginId" },
  { "mData": "Name" },
  { "mData": "CreatedDate" }
]
```

For undefined length, I have tried the following code and it's working:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
 "aLengthMenu": [[100, 200, 300], [100, 200, 300]],
  "iDisplayLength": 100,
  "iDisplayStart" : 0,
  "bProcessing": true,
  "bServerSide": true,
  "sAjaxSource": "GetUser.ashx",
  "sServerMethod": "POST",
  "sAjaxDataProp" : "",
  "aoColumnDefs": [ {
    "aTargets": [ 0 ],
    "mData": "download_link",
    "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
      return '<a href="/UserDetail.aspx?ID='+data+'">Detail</a>';
    }
  } ],
  "aoColumns": [
    { "mData": null },
    { "mData": "LoginId" },
    { "mData": "Name" },
    { "mData": "CreatedDate" }
  ]
});
```

The reference site to know more about `aLengthMenu` is:

https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#aLengthMenu

Answer (score 9):

Your `"sAjaxDataProp" : ""` is set to an empty string, which causes this error.

dataTables expects to have a string here to tell under which key your server returned data can be found.
This defaults to aaData, so your json should include this key amongst all others that might be returned or needed by pagination etc.

Normal serversided json:

```
{
"iTotalRecords":"6",
"iTotalDisplayRecords":"6",
"aaData": [
    [
        "1",
        "sameek",
        "sam",
        "sam",
        "sameek@test.com",
        "1",
        ""
    ],...
```

Since all values are in aaData you don't need sAjaxDataProp at all.

Modified serverside json:

```
{
"iTotalRecords":"6",
"iTotalDisplayRecords":"6",
"myData": [
    [
        "1",
        "sameek",
        "sam",
        "sam",
        "sameek@test.com",
        "1",
        ""
    ],
```

Now the values are in myData. so you need to tell dataTables where to find the actual data by setting:

```
"sAjaxDataProp" : "myData"
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JDtvxzTWvm0nWwEPJBUu?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

If you see this error, look at the json returned from the server, and then make sure that all of your datatable 'mData' values have matching entry. If you are also using a bean, check there as well.

And there is no need specify 'tr', 'td', etc for the table. It is much cleaner if you let jquery do that for you. Here is what my tables look like:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="myTable" style="table-layout:fixed" ></table>
```

and then my datatable elements specify the width and column title:

```
{sTitle: "Column A", sWidth: "100px", mData: "idStringFromJson", bSortable: false},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#example').DataTable({..` (capital D) instead of `$('#example').dataTable({..`

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this problem, it was actually the result of an un-applied migration.  I had restored a backup of the database, which hadn't yet had one of my recent schema migrations run on it, and once I ran migrations, everything worked fine.