# Jquery Datatables and Jeditable - Data is not displaying

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, jeditable

I am using Jquery DataTables and jEditable. I have a correct JSON response as follows:

```
[{"country_id":"18","country":"Aruba","country_enabled":"1"},{"country_id":"19","country":"Afghanistan","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"22","country":"Angola","country_enabled":"1"},{"country_id":"23","country":"Anguilla","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"24","country":"\u00c5land Islands","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"25","country":"Albania","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"26","country":"Andorra","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"27","country":"United Arab Emirates","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"29","country":"Argentina","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"30","country":"Armenia","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"31","country":"American Samoa","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"32","country":"Antarctica","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"33","country":"French Southern Territories","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"34","country":"Antigua and Barbuda","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"35","country":"Australia","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"36","country":"Austria","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"37","country":"Azerbaijan","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"38","country":"Burundi","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"39","country":"Belgium","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"40","country":"Benin","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"41","country":"Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"42","country":"Burkina Faso","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"43","country":"Bangladesh","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"44","country":"Bulgaria","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"45","country":"zoo","country_enabled":null},{"country_id":"46","country":"Xylaphone","country_enabled":null}]
```

The above is taken from Chrome's developer tools and from the XHR window and, therefore, I know the response looks correct and the data is being received.

Here is my HTML to display the data:

```
<div class="content">
<div id="pad-wrapper" class="form-page">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>List of Countries</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="bs-example">
            </br>
            <form>
<div align = "left">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.location='<?php echo site_url("admin/country_add");?>'">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add Country
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="window.location='<?php echo site_url("admin/country_delete");?>'">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Delete Countries
                </button>
            </div>

            <!-- start table listing -->
     <table id="myDataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>country_id</th>
            <th>country</th>
            <th>country_enabled</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>         
    </tbody>

</table>
<button id="btnAddNewRow">Add</button>
<button id="btnDeleteRow">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The datatable appears in the view but just says, "loading..." and no data is ever displayed.

I have renamed the column headers the same as my database but it still does not display the data.

There is an error in the console as follows:
[image]

Comment: can you please check it out in console is their any error..?

Comment: I had added the console error.  Not sure if related.  Thanks for helping!

Comment: can your just refer "http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6101/cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-with-ajax-source" and "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470411/datatables-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined" they also having problem like you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the client-side processing mode data provided via Ajax should have the following structure, see [ajax](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option for more details.

```
{
    "data": [
        // row 1 data source,
        // row 2 data source,
        // etc
    ]
}
```

The solution is to correct your JSON data to look like:

```
{ 
    "data": [
        {"country_id":"18","country":"Aruba","country_enabled":"1"}
    ]
}
```

Alternative solution is to set [ajax.dataSrc](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) to empty string to indicate that you're returning plain array, see the sample code below:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  "ajax": {
    "url": "data.json",
    "dataSrc": ""
  }
});
```

Comment: Indeed, the above solution worked.  I am curious why data worked and when I use aaData it doesn't work.  Thank you very much for the above solution!

Comment: @user3264461, `aaData` is a property name of older version of DataTables 1.9. However, DataTables 1.10 is backward compatible and `aaData` should have worked, see [ajax.dataSrc](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc#Default).

Comment: i tried again with aaData and it works.  this is my code;   function get_countries(){
  $results = array();         
  $results['aaData'] = $this->db->select('country_id, country, country_enabled ')
     ->from('mhcountry')
     ->get()
     ->result();
  return $results;
 }