# sorting not working datatable plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

[DataTables Cannot read property 'length' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470411/datatables-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined/38094085#38094085)

I have same problem like the above link. I have a link to json data.

My JQUERY:

`$('#card-table').DataTable({
     "ajax": "http://project-maria-1350.appspot.com/getPeople?key=CX1231466035200"
 });`

My HTML code:

```
`<div id="passenger" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <table id="card-table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Nationality</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Boarding No.</th>
            <th>Seat No.</th>
            <th>Group Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>`
```

I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.the data is displayed. But sorting is not working.
Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Does your number of columns coming from back-end are same as specified in the HTML ? Please check it as most of the times this causes the undefined length problem.

Comment: are you getting this error on sorting based on any specific field? Chck this plunker based on your code and data https://plnkr.co/edit/9ug2unk2kc4NuGLbvW2v?p=preview , i dont see any issue there.

Comment: No, it is not the same problem at all. First of all your data is not JSON, it is an array of array of strings; furthermore your server script has no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, therefore useless in a browser based dataTables context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data tables expects the JSON object to have the format `{"data": [{..,..},{...,...}]}`.

Check this example https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html 
(click the tab "AJAX" and see the format).

You can change it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. No errors now. But, still sorting is not working. I need to change my JSON structure. Any Idea to convert my data to JSON?

Comment: Ok. You have to show me your backend code. Is it PHP with SQL?

Comment: I solved it. Thanks.