# jQuery Datatable Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I see this is a popular question.  I'm posting my question because I've tried to investigate my issue with others on SO to no avail.

**------------------I'm using the legacy jquery datatable---------------------**

I'm seeing inconsistent behavior.  I have two datatables that are the same in every way except each is communicating with a different controller.  One populates perfectly and the other gives me this error in the jQuery code.

[image]

I am getting the json data but the _fnGetObjectDataFn( oSettings.sAjaxDataProp )(json) is setting aData to undefined!  **Say what?**  Here is the json data:

[image]

To be sure the issue is not with the incorrect number of columns, I've minimized my table to be only one column.  Here's the javaScript for the popup table view:

```
initBuildingsTable = function () {

    $('#selectableAssetTable').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "SiteName", "bSortable": true },
        ],
        "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "mDataProp": null, "sDefaultContent": " ", "aTargets": [-1] }
        ],
        "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"><"clear">',
        "oLanguage": {
            "sEmptyTable": "No data found."
        },
        "sAjaxSource": $.baseURL("api/selfservice/getsites"),
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: sSource, // Do not add the base to this.  It should already be present
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: fnCallback,
                complete: function () {
                    alert("show me the data!")
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the HTML for the table:

```
<table id="selectableAssetTable" style="width: 100%; ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>Site Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the DTO for the data returning from the controller:

```
public class SiteDTO
{
    public decimal SiteId { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: First of all check `api/selfservice/getsites` api returns valid json or not..https://stackoverflow.com/a/22470507/5737771

Comment: What should *_fnGetObjectDataFn( oSettings.sAjaxDataProp )* be ?

Comment: @Jonasw - It should be an Array[362]

Comment: @patricia so if you call it with (json) it probably throws an error ? :/

Comment: OK.  You are on to something here.  When I call the popup that works, the json data is an object that contains aaData, which is an Array[362].  When I call the popup that is NOT working, the json data is an Array[363].

Comment: @Jonasw - I was wrong in above comment!  I should return an Object that contains the aaData as the Array.  I hope this helps somebody else.  Thanks for helping me see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see `oSettings.sAjaxDataProp = "aaData"` in the watch window, so you should be looking for an Object named "aaData" to iterate through. But you are using "aData" which is by default undefined.

Comment: It's those subtle differences that'll get you every time! :-)